# How to append the external object to Series index

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a multiple Pandas Series that looks like below:

```
s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3], index=[0, 1, 2])
s.index.name = 'id'
```

Each series refers to some group, with a known id. I'd like to add these id stored as a one int variable (`group_id`) as a first level of Series MultiIndex. So the resulting Series would look like this:

```
group_id  id
41        0     1
          1     2
          2     3
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For MultiIndex in `Series` is necessary reassign new one, e.g. created by [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3], index=[0, 1, 2])
s.index.name = 'id'
group_id  = 42

s.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[group_id], s.index], names=['group_id','id'])
print (s)
group_id  id
42        0     1
          1     2
          2     3
dtype: int64
```